# Proper way of constructing MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one controller with 2 actions.

The first action using Entity Framework to get a list of requests from a database, and then a view displays them.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult HelpRequests()
    {
        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var items = context.Requests.ToList();
            return View(items);
        }
    }
}
```

The view is:

```
@model List<Request>
@foreach (var request in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => request.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => request.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => request.Message)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(mode => request.CreateDate)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Reply", "SendResponse", new { id = request.Id })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

And finally the model for a request is

```
public partial class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Responded { get; set; }
}
```

If you look at the view code I output a link which will take the user to Home/SendResponse/id

This is where my uncertainty comes in.

The purpose of the SendResponse action is to reply to a specific request. On the SendResponse view I would like to show some of the request model fields so the author knows what to include in a response.

My specific questions are

1. Because I want to display some data from the request model, the model for the view will be set to the request model, but the purpose of the view will be to send a response (which is defined in the response model). So should I just set some ViewBag.* properties which are set to fields in the request class, and use those instead of the request model, and then set my view model to response?
2. Is it okay/best practice to have one controller for dealing with two models (in this case requests and responses)?

In short, I am just not 100% certain on how to structure a MVC combination which takes data from one model and then creates a new model based on that data.

Comment: In the SendResponse controller action you can get the Request data for the provided id from the db. You can create another model class which can wrap the request data from the db and any additional data which you want to display in SendResponse View.

Comment: It is always OK to create customized model class based on the data which you want to display on the view.

Comment: Better to set another viewmodel which wraps both models, due to views accept only single model binding mechanism. The created viewmodel can be customized to contain certain part of data you want to pass into view.

Answer (score 0):

A typical pattern is to create a model per view. In your code you are directly sending the Request object from your database. Usually one would create a RequestViewModel and send this to the view to work against.

When the author clicks on your link you'll receive a Request ID. You use the ID to retrieve the relevant Request object from your DB, then project it into a ResponseEditModel. You include/declare some fields in this model that you want to include from your request object. You basically copy them over.

A controller can work with many models, I would actually recommend doing a model per view in most cases. Most important is to keep the controller cohesive somehow, like the handling of request and processing the responses, sounds fine.

Comment: Ah okay, so my request model is a class which represents the data in the database, and you are saying to then marshal the data from request to a requestview model,for the view, and a responseview model for the send response view.  I like this approach